# magento layout xml files: getChildHtml() again

Tags: magento-1.7

I've asked this question before and gotten some replies but did not understand them.
Here is the contents of my 1column.phtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
  <head>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
  </head>
  <body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
      <div class="page">
        <div class="col-outer-left outer-sidebar">
          <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('outer-left') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="main-container col1-layout">
          <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
          <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
            <div class="col-main">
              <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
          <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-outer-right outer-sidebar">
          <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('outer-right') ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the layout I want. The centre portion is going to be fixed width. But the outer-left and outer-right are variable width and I want to occasionally place stuff there. However, I do not know how to fill them up. When $this->getChildHtml('outer-right') gets called were does it get it PHP from? I have made up this outer-right string because this is the layout for one-column and the layout for three-column pages also has these extra outer portions (making the design almost like 5 columns).

Inside app/design/frontend/default/layout/cms.xml I find the line:

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <label>CMS Home Page</label>
</cms_index_index>
```

It has been suggested that I replace this line. I do not understand where this cms_inde_index code is being called from. I don't even know how to search the
source code for appearances of cms_index_index.

Please help me understand magneto. I am really stuck.

---

Note: I want the home page to use 1column.phtml and display something in the
outer-left portion, and some other 1column.phtml to display something else in
the right column. How do I achieve this?

Note: under CMS -> Pages I can select between 1 column, 2 col left, 2 col right,
3 col, or empty. I was thinking that in my circumstnace I might even have to add
to this list if I cannot accomplish what I'm after in a simpler way, but I cannot
find anywhere in the documentation how to augment this list, nor where the
mapping between these names and the respective phtml files is found.

---

OK, So I've added the following file to my design package theme's layout directory:

```
File: local.xml
Contents:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <cms_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
      <block type="core/template" name="outer-right" template="page/outer-right.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

This successfully adds the output of the outer-right.phtml template in the correct place
but only when viewing the main page. I now want this to be output with all pages,
including those with the layouts:

1column.phtml        2columns-right.phtml
2columns-left.phtml  3columns.phtml

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The name used in the XML is what is called in the PHP when you use `->getChildHtml('outer-right')`. The .phtml file is declared in the XML, for instance: `<block type="core/template" template="page/html/outer-right.phtml" name="outer-right" />`. The "template=" points to the phtml file it's using for the block, and calling the getChildHtml in the parent block's phtml will put it where it belongs. Note that some default template files use `->getChildHtml('')` to automatically call all child blocks.

Comment: Thanks Jason, but I am still struggling to have my template included in all pages. Seems like I am looking for a different handle and block to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the app/design/frontend/mypackage/default/layout/local.xml
that adds the extra columns to all pages. The handles that are
commented out have been commented because they only apply to
pages configured as CMS pages via the admin panel.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <default>
    <reference name="root">
      <block type="core/template" name="outer-left" template="page/outer-left.phtml" />
      <block type="core/template" name="outer-right" template="page/outer-right.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </default>
   <!--
  <page_one_column>
    <reference name="root">
      <block type="core/template" name="outer-left" template="page/outer-left.phtml" />
      <block type="core/template" name="outer-right" template="page/outer-right.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </page_one_column>
  <page_two_columns_left>
    <reference name="root">
      <block type="core/template" name="outer-left" template="page/outer-left.phtml" />
      <block type="core/template" name="outer-right" template="page/outer-right.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </page_two_columns_left>
  <page_two_columns_right>
    <reference name="root">
      <block type="core/template" name="outer-left" template="page/outer-left.phtml" />
      <block type="core/template" name="outer-right" template="page/outer-right.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </page_two_columns_right>
  <page_three_columns>
    <reference name="root">
      <block type="core/template" name="outer-left" template="page/outer-left.phtml" />
      <block type="core/template" name="outer-right" template="page/outer-right.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </page_three_columns>
  -->
</layout>
```